# What does the ` symbol mean in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

What does the `` ` `` symbol actually mean in MySQL?

This works:

```
INSERT INTO person(`name`, `roll_no`, `gender`) VALUES('person1', 1, 'male');
```

Whereas this throws a syntax error:

```
INSERT INTO person(name, roll_no, gender) VALUES('person1', 1, 'male');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 8):

The `` ` `` just tells MySQL to expect a column name, since `name` is a reserved keyword in SQL.

`` SELECT `name` `` in MySQL is the equivalent of `SELECT [name]` in T-SQL.

---

**Bonus:**

I highly recommend using [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) instead of the usual phpMyAdmin. One of the great advantages of using a proper management studio is that this would've been quite obvious:

[image]

Notice that `name` is highlighted differently, showing that it is a reserved keyword, and needs to be escaped as `` `name` ``.

Comment: It's worth noting that neither the backtick nor Microsoft's `[..]` are valid in standard SQL. The SQL standard requires double quotes to quote identifiers with "illegal" characters. Both, MySQL and SQL Server do also accept (or can be configured to accept) object names quoted according to the SQL standard (e.g. `"name"`)

Comment: `name` is NOT a reserved keyword, and does not need to be escaped. That said, I agree that keywords should be avoided where possible, and reserved (key)words should be avoided altogether.